How to follow a BodyComponent using the Forge2DGame camera?
I try follow a single object but does not work, i read other examples and posts like as Camera doesn't follow player in Flutter Flame but does not work in my code:
import 'package:flame/game.dart' show Vector2;
import 'package:flame/events.dart' show TapCallbacks, TapDownEvent;
import 'package:flame/camera.dart' show FixedResolutionViewport, CameraComponent;
import 'package:flame_forge2d/flame_forge2d.dart' show Forge2DGame;
import '../objects/ball.dart' show BallBody;
import '../objects/ground.dart' show GroundBody;

class PlayScreen extends Forge2DGame with TapCallbacks {

    PlayScreen() :
        super(
            gravity: Vector2(0, 100),
            camera: CameraComponent.withFixedResolution(width: 2400 / 2, height: 1080 / 2),
        );

    BallBody? _ballBody = null;
    GroundBody? _groundBody = null;
    CameraComponent? _cameraComponent = null;

    @override
    Future<void> onLoad() async {
        super.onLoad();

        /* // Add the camera
        _cameraComponent = CameraComponent();
        _cameraComponent!.viewport = FixedResolutionViewport(resolution: Vector2(size.x, size.y));
        add(_cameraComponent!); */

        // Create ground
        _groundBody = GroundBody(
            Vector2(0, size.y - 40), // Position XY
            size.x,
            40
        );
        add(_groundBody!);

        // Create ball
        _ballBody = BallBody(
            Vector2((size.x / 2) - 20, (size.y / 2) - 20), // Position XY
            20.0 // Radius size
        );
        add(_ballBody!);

        // Camera follow the ball
        camera.follow(_ballBody!);
    }

    @override
    void onTapDown(TapDownEvent event) {
        if(_ballBody != null)
            _ballBody!.applyImpulse(Vector2(100, -200));

        add(BallBody(event.localPosition, 20.0));
    }
}

Where could be the problem of why the camera does not follow the ball after it appears and bounces?
The ball:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart' show Canvas, Offset;
import 'package:flame/game.dart' show Vector2;
import 'package:flame/palette.dart' show BasicPalette;
import 'package:flame_forge2d/flame_forge2d.dart' show BodyComponent, Body, BodyDef, FixtureDef, BodyType, CircleShape;

class BallBody extends BodyComponent {

    final Vector2 position;
    final double radius;

    BallBody(this.position, this.radius);
    
    @override
    Body createBody() {
        final shape = CircleShape()..radius = radius;
        final fixtureDef = FixtureDef(shape)
            ..density = 5
            ..friction = .5
            ..restitution = .5;

        final bodyDef = BodyDef()
            ..type = BodyType.dynamic
            ..position = position;

        return world.createBody(bodyDef)..createFixture(fixtureDef);
    }

    void applyImpulse(Vector2 impulse) {
        // body.applyForce(impulse);
        // body.applyLinearImpulse(impulse);
        body.linearVelocity = impulse;
    }

    @override
    void renderCircle(Canvas canvas, Offset center, double radius) {
        super.renderCircle(canvas, center, radius);

        canvas.drawLine(center, center + Offset(0, radius), BasicPalette.blue.paint());
        canvas.rotate(body.angle);
    }
}


You have added the BodyComponents to the game class instead of to the Forge2DWorld.
Just change add(_groundBody!); to world.add(_groundBody!); and
add(_ballBody!); to world.add(_ballBody!); and the camera should be able to track your component.
